# How do you configure IIS to display at proper size on mobile devices, is it viewport?

Tags: iis, web-server, mobile-devices

I have a web app that is targeted to mobile devices.  It displays fine on old devices with a screen size around 320px wide, but it displays as a little postage stamp in the corner of the screen on newer devices with higher screen resolutions.

I've been looking at browser capabilities files on the IIS config side and the viewport meta tag on the app dev side but I'm still not sure what I need to do to make sure that my app displays at a reasonable resolution on different mobile browsers.  Anybody been through this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is something that needs to be handled in code, not through IIS config.  You'd be better off taking this over to [StackOverflow.com](http://StackOverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring sites for mobile devices is something that is done in the code, rather than IIS, as each type of mobile devices has different capabilities. You can use API's like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or the [mobile device browser file](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) for asp.net to determine the capabilities of the mobile device accessing the site and produce content to meet these capabilities, including screen size.